# Combining bounding box with xy coordinates in R

Tags: r, overlay, xy

I am just beginning a side project to start learning something about spatial analysis using data from match play events in a particular sport. I have some xy coordinates of shots taken at goal and in this sport all shots have to be taken within a scoring circle. This is not a true 'circle' but a flat-topped semi-circle that when plotted looks like this:
[image]
I'd like to create a bounding box that uses the circle coordinates and then analyse the shot data within this circle bounding box. I have gone through a process of trying to create a bounding box from the xy coordinates of the circle:

```
x_coords<-(Circleshape2$x)
y_coords<-(Circleshape2$y)
poly1 <- sp::Polygon(cbind(x_coords,y_coords))
firstPoly <- sp::Polygons(list(poly1), ID = "A")
str(firstPoly,1)
firstPoly <- sp::Polygons(list(poly1), ID = "A")
CirclePoly <- sp::SpatialPolygons(list(firstPoly))
#and saving it as a shape file
shapefile(x = CirclePoly, file = "./file.shp")
D <- read_sf(dsn = "./Circle Shape", layer = "file")
Cbound<-as.owin(D)
```

and I get a owin object that hopefully looks good for a 'scoring circle' bounding box
[image: Scoring circle 'bounding box']

then I did the following using the xy coordinates of the shots at goal:

```
x_coords2<-(xGxyonly$x)
y_coords2<-(xGxyonly$y)
head(cbind(x_coords2,y_coords2))

Shots <- SpatialPoints(coords = cbind(x_coords2,y_coords2))

shapefile(x = Shots, file = "~/Shots shape files/Shots.shp")
```

and the shot distribution looks like this.

[image]

I have looked around but I am very confused about how to 'tell' R that I want the shots data to be 'bounded' within the circle, Cbound owin or shape file, so the analyses I'm trying to learn (point pattern, cluster etc) is being carried out in the correct space. All of the coordinates are xy relevant to the dimensions of the pitch. I'm sure this is really simple but my coding ability is somewhat rudimentary and spatial knowledge pretty much non-existent (I use R for some statistical analysis - regression, glms etc and have no background in the spatial side of things).
What may have I missed or be doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, welcome to GIS.SE! First tip: the `sp` package got replaced by its authors in favour of the `sf` package, so I recommend you to use `sf`. You can find a good guide [here](https://www.paulamoraga.com/book-spatial/spatial-data-in-r.html). Second: the function you are after is called `sf::st_intersection` , but I'm not sure you can use it right away since your XY-coordinates are unusual for spatial analysis. You might need to recalculate the XY coordinates to a coordinate reference system first.

Comment: Its hard to tell what's actually wrong here since we don't have your data and there's no way of relating your points to your polygon. Does your last figure (showing all the points) include points outside the polygon (penultimate figure)? Hard to tell.

Comment: @saQuist - Thanks for the reply. Yes just having xy was confusing because the vast majority of examples seemed to have long:lat and real world references whereas I just want my points of interest (shots, passes, turnovers etc) to be associated with dimensions of the pitch (a simple rectangle (0,55),(0,91.4)) or in the scoring circle (which is part of the pitch of course) as above. Thanks for the code and I’ll have a look at the sf package but I think I’ve started to get somewhere with the 'spatstat' package (see below response to @Spacedman).

Comment: @Spacedman - I should have included some data but I hoped this was a simple answer that I was just missing. I think using the 'spatstat' package and Baddeley et al.’s “Spatial Point Patterns:..” book I've started to get somewhere by simply joining the polygon and data with:  X<-ppp(data$x,data$y,Cbound). This has allowed me to start looking at the shot distribution a little. Many thanks for your comment.